# IEnumerable<type> is false in code but true in Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, immediate-window

Debugging some code I came across an "is IEnumerable" comparison, which confusingly evaluates to false in code but true in the Immediate Window.

I wonder if anyone can shed light to why this would happen?

Example:

```
public enum Fruit
{
    Apples,
    Strawberries
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    object myObj = new Fruit[] { Fruit.Apples, Fruit.Strawberries };

    bool isListOfEnums = myObj is IEnumerable<Fruit>; // True

    isListOfEnums = myObj is IEnumerable<Enum>; // False in code, but True in Immediate Window when debugged
}
```

(Immediate Window)

```
? myObj is IEnumerable<Enum>    
true
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a quirk of the intermediate window, basically. There are some pieces of code which evaluate differently there - it's one reason I generally prefer not to use the intermediate window.

An `IEnumerable<Fruit>` *isn't* an `IEnumerable<Enum>`. Each element of the latter would be a reference, as `Enum` is a reference type (just like `ValueType` is - I know, it's confusing) whereas each element of an `IEnumerable<Fruit>` is a `Fruit` value (not a reference).

Comment: Thanks Jon, watches also seem to be the same as the Immediate Window in this situation, guess I can no longer trust either.

Answer (score -1):

Try quick watch to see the changes in the value of `isListOfEnums`.
Or you can check its value multiple times in immediate window. You'll see it is being evaluated correctly. This is what I got and think working properly:-

```
?isListOfEnums
false
?isListOfEnums
true
?isListOfEnums
false
```

- when `public void SomeMethod()` is invoked, value of isListOfEnums is
  `false`.
- after `myObj is IEnumerable<Fruit>;` is evaluated, it becomes `true`.
- after `myObj is IEnumerable<Enum>;` is evaluated, it beomes `false` again.